# Ошибка при создании cookie

Tags: javascript, php, веб-программирование, битрикс, cookie

Я смотрел [10. Избранное. 01. Скрипт добавления товара в избранное](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_OFUZXPKbg&list=PL90VyUHz4BpFhObHt2VVW3tAyUMcJ4kL1&index=39) с 11:30-13:30 и смотрел [10. Избранное. 02. Добавление в избранное из карточка товара](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bCM2sDel__w&list=PL90VyUHz4BpFhObHt2VVW3tAyUMcJ4kL1&index=40). Там приведен код добавления и удаления элемента массива (товара в Избранное) в сookie

При щелчке на кнопке В избранное

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

выдает следующую ошибку

```
mylasttechnoshop.ru/:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'M', "M_SOUND_LO"... is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at actionFav (template_6562e590b8b8f11da8d97dd8909fa6e1_v1.js?1683716626196502:89:22)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (template_6562e590b8b8f11da8d97dd8909fa6e1_v1.js?1683716626196502:80:4)
    at HTMLBodyElement.dispatch (template_6562e590b8b8f11da8d97dd8909fa6e1_v1.js?1683716626196502:5:10315)
    at q.handle (template_6562e590b8b8f11da8d97dd8909fa6e1_v1.js?1683716626196502:5:8342)
actionFav @ template_6562e590b8b8f11da8d97dd8909fa6e1_v1.js?1683716626196502:89
(anonymous) @ template_6562e590b8b8f11da8d97dd8909fa6e1_v1.js?1683716626196502:80
dispatch @ template_6562e590b8b8f11da8d97dd8909fa6e1_v1.js?1683716626196502:5
q.handle @ template_6562e590b8b8f11da8d97dd8909fa6e1_v1.js?1683716626196502:5
mylasttechnoshop.ru/:1
```

Файл, в котором создаются cookie имеет вид

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    //слайдер на главной
    $(".index_slider").bxSlider({
        mode: 'fade',
        touchEnabled: false
    });
    
    //стилизация форм
    $(".filter_bl input:checkbox, .filter_bl input:radio, .styler input:radio, .styler input:checkbox, .styler select, .styler input:file").styler();
    
    //табы в детальной
    $('body').on('click', 'ul.tabs li:not(.current)', function() {
        $(this).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current')
            .parents('div.section').find('div.box').eq($(this).index()).fadeIn(150).siblings('div.box').hide();             
    });
    
    //слайдер в детальной
    $(".det_slider").bxSlider({
       mode:'fade',
       controls: false,
       pagerCustom: '#det_pager'
    });
    $(".det_pager").bxSlider({
       minSlides: 1,
       maxSlides: 4,
       moveSlides: 1,
       slideWidth: 70,
       slideMargin: 20,
       pager: false,
       infiniteLoop: false
    });
    
    $("body").on('click', '.favor_bt', function() {
        let id = $(this).data('id');
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            actionFav('del', id);
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        } else {
            actionFav('add', id);
            $(this).addClass('active');         
        };
        
        return false;
    });
    
function actionFav(action, id) 
{
    var favorite = JSON.parse(getCookie('favorite'));
    if (favorite == null || !(favorite instanceof Array))
        favorite = [];
    
    var inArr = false;
    // проверим существование товара в массиве избранного
    for (i=0; i<favorite.length; i++) {
        if (favorite[i] == id) {
            if (action == 'del') { favorite.splice(i, 1); };
            inArr = true;
        }
    }
    
    // если товара нет в корзине, то добавим
    if (action == 'add' && (!inArr)) { favorite.push(id); };
    var d = new Date();
    d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1);
    setCookie ('favorite', JSON.stringify(favorite), d.toUTCString(), '/');
    
    return favorite;
}


function setCookie (name, value, expires, path, domain, secure) 
{
    document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) +
        ((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires : "") +
        ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") +
        ((domain) ? "; domain" + domain : "") +
        ((secure) ? "; secure" + secure : "");
}

function getCookie(name)
{
    var cookie = " " + document.cookie;
    var search = " " + name + "=";
    var setStr = null;
    var offset = 0;
    var end = 0;
    if (cookie.length > 0) {
        offset = cookie.indexOf(search);
        if (offset != 1) {
            offset += search.length;
            end = cookie.indexOf(";", offset);
            if (end != -1) {
                end = cookie.length;
            }
            setStr = unescape(cookie.substring(offset, end));
        }
    }
    
    return setStr;
}   
});
```

Как устранить ошибку?

P.S. Перед

```
var favorite = JSON.parse(getCookie('favorite'));
```

вывел с помощью

```
console.log(getCookie('favorite'));
```

и получил

```
M_SOUND_LOGIN_PLAYED=Y; BITRIX_SM_GUEST_ID=1; by=ID; sort=ASC; BX_USER_ID=67d746fcc40c5f11f4bf433377a26694; BITRIX_CONVERSION_CONTEXT_s1={"ID":1,"EXPIRE":1683752340,"UNIQUE":["conversion_visit_day"]}; BITRIX_SM_SALE_UID=233876e435a02034b36c4e8bfbe22e45; BITRIX_SM_LAST_SETTINGS=; BITRIX_SM_LAST_VISIT=10.05.2023 15:25:13
```

Еще забыл упомянуть, что ссылка В избранное имеет вид

```
<a class="favor_bt <?=(in_array($arResult['ID'], $arParams['FAVORITE']) ? 'active' : '');?>" data-id="<?=$arResult['ID']?>" href="javascript:;">В избранное</a>
```

Также из инструментов разработчика есть следующая информация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну так посмотрите, что вы в куку избранного кладете, на каждом шаге

Comment: @DaemonHK при щелчке на кнопку ничего не происходит - даже не создается кука.

Comment: за вас код ковырять никто не будет... идите построчно в actionFav()

Comment: судя по ошибке, в куке находится строка `M_SOUND_LO` вместо `{` на первом месте, что не может распарситься как json

Comment: @DmitryKozlov Как устранить ошибку? Что значит M_SOUND_LO мне совершенно не понятно.

Comment: @bitrixfinder `M_SOUND_LOGIN_PLAYED=Y; BITRIX_SM_GUEST_ID=1; by=ID;` - это не json, это текст, разделенный `;`. Не надо его парсить как json

Comment: Вы делаете `JSON.stringify()` для второго параметра здесь `setCookie('favorite', JSON.stringify(favorite), d.toUTCString(), '/');`, но когда получаете куки, пытаетесь спарсить весь куки как JSON здесь `JSON.parse(getCookie('favorite'));`.

Comment: @DmitryKozlov в куке favorite хранятся id-шники товаров, для которых была щелкнута кнопка В избранное. Как добиться, чтобы в куке хранились только айдишники (чтобы программа работала)?

Comment: @Simon как устранить ошибку?

Comment: Обратите внимание на свой же код `console.log(getCookie('favorite'));`, посмотрите где конкретно там JSON.

Comment: @bitrixfinder в функции `getCookie` стоит `offset = cookie.indexOf(search);` и проверяется как `if (offset != 1)`, т.е условие срабатывает, если смещение не во второй позиции, даже если ваш ид отсутствует в куках. Наверное подразумевалось `if (offset != -1)`

Answer (score 3):

Опечатка в функции `getCookie`: вместо

```
if (offset != 1) {
```

должно быть

```
if (offset != -1) {
```