# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование, битрикс, cookie

Я смотрел [10. Избранное. 01. Скрипт добавления товара в избранное](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_OFUZXPKbg&list=PL90VyUHz4BpFhObHt2VVW3tAyUMcJ4kL1&index=39) с 11:30-13:30 и смотрел [10. Избранное. 02. Добавление в избранное из карточка товара](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bCM2sDel__w&list=PL90VyUHz4BpFhObHt2VVW3tAyUMcJ4kL1&index=40). Там приведен код добавления и удаления элемента массива (товара в Избранное) в сookie

При щелчках на кнопке В избранное

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

выдает следующие ошибки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первый щелчок на В избранное срабатывает, а другие нет (не удается выделить кнопку)

Файл, в котором создаются cookie имеет вид

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    //слайдер на главной
    $(".index_slider").bxSlider({
        mode: 'fade',
        touchEnabled: false
    });
    
    //стилизация форм
    $(".filter_bl input:checkbox, .filter_bl input:radio, .styler input:radio, .styler input:checkbox, .styler select, .styler input:file").styler();
    
    //табы в детальной
    $('body').on('click', 'ul.tabs li:not(.current)', function() {
        $(this).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current')
            .parents('div.section').find('div.box').eq($(this).index()).fadeIn(150).siblings('div.box').hide();             
    });
    
    //слайдер в детальной
    $(".det_slider").bxSlider({
       mode:'fade',
       controls: false,
       pagerCustom: '#det_pager'
    });
    $(".det_pager").bxSlider({
       minSlides: 1,
       maxSlides: 4,
       moveSlides: 1,
       slideWidth: 70,
       slideMargin: 20,
       pager: false,
       infiniteLoop: false
    });
    
    $("body").on('click', '.favor_bt', function() {
        console.log('Вход в click');
        let id = $(this).data('id');
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            actionFav('del', id);
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        } else {
            actionFav('add', id);
            $(this).addClass('active');         
        };
        
        return false;
    });
    
function actionFav(action, id) 
{
    console.log('Вход');
    console.log(getCookie('favorite'));
    var favorite = JSON.parse(getCookie('favorite'));
    
    console.log(favorite);
    if (favorite == null || !(favorite instanceof Array))
        favorite = [];
    
    console.log(favorite);
    
    var inArr = false;
    // проверим существование товара в массиве избранного
    for (i=0; i<favorite.length; i++) {
        if (favorite[i] == id) {
            if (action == 'del') { favorite.splice(i, 1); };
            inArr = true;
        }
    }
    
    // если товара нет в корзине, то добавим
    if (action == 'add' && (!inArr)) { favorite.push(id); };
    var d = new Date();
    d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1);
    setCookie ('favorite', JSON.stringify(favorite), d.toUTCString(), '/');
    
    return favorite;
}


function setCookie (name, value, expires, path, domain, secure) 
{
    document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) +
        ((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires : "") +
        ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") +
        ((domain) ? "; domain" + domain : "") +
        ((secure) ? "; secure" + secure : "");
}

function getCookie(name)
{
    var cookie = " " + document.cookie;
    var search = " " + name + "=";
    var setStr = null;
    var offset = 0;
    var end = 0;
    if (cookie.length > 0) {
        offset = cookie.indexOf(search);
        if (offset != -1) {
            offset += search.length;
            end = cookie.indexOf(";", offset);
            if (end != -1) {
                end = cookie.length;
            }
            setStr = unescape(cookie.substring(offset, end));
        }
    }
    
    return setStr;
}   
});
```

Как устранить ошибку?

Что значит текст этой ошибки я знаю, но не понимаю почему она возникла, как ее устранить.

Я конечно понимаю, что это очень схоже с [Ошибка-при-создании-cookie](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1518780/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-cookie) (для тех кто мой вопрос сочтет дублем), но как устранить **мою** ошибку не понимаю.

Comment: Вам там ответ написали, если что.

Comment: @Simon я исправил - **см. код в этом вопросе**. Я внес исправления в код, но **это не помогло**.

Comment: Почему не приняли чужой ответ который Вам подошел? Ну а так, по тексту ошибки у Вас невалидный JSON. Посмотрите на свой же `console.log(getCookie('favorite'));`, он возвращает не только JSON (и вообще так-то не JSON и не строку которую можно распарсить как JSON), а Вы все равно пытаетесь все это распарсить как JSON, как Вам там и писали в комментариях.

Comment: @Simon у меня в коде в getCookiе стоит вместо `if (offset != 1) {` `if (offset != -1) {` (см. ответ Yaroslav Sergienko
), но у меня возникает **новая** ошибка - **не** `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'M', "M_SOUND_LO"... is not valid JSON`, **а** `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 5`. Читайте внимательно текст вопроса.


`

Comment: И? `getCookie('favorite')` возвращает Вам вот это: `BITRIX_CONVERSION_CONTEXT_s1={"ID":1,"EXPIRE":1683752340,"UNIQUE":["conversion_visit_day"]}; BITRIX_SM_LAST_VISIT=16.05.2023 13:24:24`. Из этого всего, вот это --  `{"ID":1,"EXPIRE":1683752340,"UNIQUE":["conversion_visit_day"]}` JSON и если он в виде строки, можете использовать `JSON.parse()` все остальное -- нет. Читайте внимательно код который пишете.

Comment: @Simon но а как устранить ошибку? Вообще у меня стоят айдишники товаров в куки favorite и один айдишник прочитало (см. **картинку с ошибкой**) - **341**. Если быть точным, то метод возвращает `[341]; BITRIX_CONVERSION_CONTEXT_s1={"ID":1,"EXPIRE":1684270740,"UNIQUE":["conversion_visit_day"]}; BITRIX_SM_LAST_VISIT=16.05.2023 13:24:24`
. Почему не добавляются другие - не пойму.

Comment: Вам нужно делать `JSON.parse()` только для того что после `BITRIX_CONVERSION_CONTEXT_s1=` и до `;` и только это `{"ID":1,"EXPIRE":1683752340,"UNIQUE":["conversion_visit_day"]}` парсить как JSON. `getCookie('favorite')` возвращает строку, в которой не только JSON, так как там не только JSON, а Вы для всего этого пытаетесь использовать `JSON.parse();`, то конечно же Вам будет выдавать ошибку, так как то что Вы туда передаете не есть валидным JSON. То есть из того что возвращает `getCookie('favorite')` Вам еще предстоит достать JSON.

Comment: Закиньте вот это `BITRIX_CONVERSION_CONTEXT_s1={"ID":1,"EXPIRE":1684270740,"UNIQUE":["conversion_visit_day"]}; BITRIX_SM_LAST_VISIT=16.05.2023 13:24:24` в любой JSON валидатор. Например: [https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Comment: @Simon смотри внимательно скриншот с ошибкой - getCookie возвращает `[341]; BITRIX_CONVERSION_CONTEXT_s1={"ID":1,"EXPIRE":1684270740,"UNIQUE":["conversion_visit_day"]}; BITRIX_SM_LAST_VISIT=16.05.2023 13:24:24`. Меня интересует 341. Значит ошибка в getCookie. **Я обновил самый первый скриншот, на котором у меня выделен товар с айдишником 341** (я его просто перенес с прошлого вопроса).

Comment: Еще раз. Ошибка в том, что `getCoockie()` возвращает НЕ ТОЛЬКО JSON СТРОКУ и Вы это передаете в `JSON.parse()`. Вы понимаете что такое JSON? Что Вы мне доказать пытаетесь, я не пойму?

Comment: @Simon как **устранить** ошибку? Ответ Yaroslav Sergienko я использовал, но он не устраняет моей новой ошибки.

Comment: Функция getCookie возвращает `[341]; BITRIX_CONVERSION_CONTEXT_s1={"ID":1,"EXPIRE":1684270740,"UNIQUE":["conversion_visit_day"]}; BITRIX_SM_LAST_VISIT=16.05.2023 13:24:24
`, а не `BITRIX_CONVERSION_CONTEXT_s1={"ID":1,"EXPIRE":1684270740,"UNIQUE":["conversion_visit_day"]}; BITRIX_SM_LAST_VISIT=16.05.2023 13:24:24`.

Comment: Окей, это что-то меняет в том что вот это `[341]; BITRIX_CONVERSION_CONTEXT_s1={"ID":1,"EXPIRE":1684270740,"UNIQUE":["conversion_visit_day"]}; BITRIX_SM_LAST_VISIT=16.05.2023 13:24:24` по прежнему не есть валидным JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опечатка в функции `getCookie`: вместо

```
if (end != -1) {
    end = cookie.length;
}
```

должно быть

```
if (end == -1) {
    end = cookie.length;
}
```

Иначе функция getCookie почти всегда будет обрезать cookie не до ближайшего `;`, а до конца строки. В итоге к JSON в конец добавляются лишние символы, которые вызывают указанную ошибку.

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что в JSON.parse() передаётся лишняя информация, следовательно её надо обрезать. Код ниже должен исправить ошибку. Просто замените переменную favorite в функции actionFav.

```
var favorite = JSON.parse(getCookie('favorite').match(/{.*}/)?.[0]);
```

Comment: мне нужно, чтобы getCookie правильно читало cookie и работало только с айдишниками товаров.

Comment: В таком случае надо класть правильные данные в куки. Либо заниматься постобработкой как в вашем случае.